# When changing page by tapping on IOs PageControl speedily, the current indicator moves ahead of the page

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uipagecontrol

In my Xamarin.IOs project, I have a UIPageControl that is combined with a Paging enabled UICollectionView.

I use the `CardPageControl.PrimaryActionTriggered` event to handle swiping the page.

```
CardPageControl.PrimaryActionTriggered += OnPageControlTapped;

private async void OnPageControlTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // SetContentOffset of the collection view
}
```

But when I speedily tap on the PageControl, the current indicator moves way ahead of the current page and then after the tapping ended, the current indicator re-positions in the correct indicator.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enable **DefersCurrentPageDisplay**. This is **false** by default.

```
CardPageControl.DefersCurrentPageDisplay = true;
```

Then inside *OnPageControlTapped*, invoke **UpdateCurrentPageDisplay()** of *CardPageControl*,

```
private async void OnPageControlTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // SetContentOffset of the collection view

    CardPageControl.UpdateCurrentPageDisplay();
}
```

This will sync the PageControl current indicator with the current page.

Comment: What is the `CardPageControl` can't find it anywhere.